# Ocaml: recursion on a list of tuples

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following function table which takes a list of tuples (x's are strings and y's are a list of strings) and I want to return a tuple of x1 and the length of the list y1. I tried it with this simple function:

```
let rec table lst = function
    | [] -> []
    | [(x1, y1, x2, y2)] -> [(x1, (List.length y1))]
    | (x1_h, y1_h, x2_h, y2_h) :: tail -> (x1_h, (List.length y1_h))::(table tail)
```

But the following error occured:

> Error: This expression has type
>            ('a * 'b list * 'c * 'd) list -> ('a * int) list
>          but an expression was expected of type ('a * int) list

I'm not really sure what I did wrong there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`function` takes an argument implicitly and pattern matches on that. In other words:

```
let f = function | ...
```

is equivalent to

```
let f lst = match lst with | ...
```

So when you write

```
let rec table lst = function | ...
```

That translates to

```
let rec table lst lst2 = match lst2 with | ...
```

The error points to the recursive call, `table tail`, because it is partially applied and returns a function `('a * 'b list * 'c * 'd) list -> ('a * int)`. `table tail tail` would return `('a * int list)` as expected and is completely valid. But since `lst` is unused in your function, you can just remove it instead.